# How can I disabble selection of weekend with FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, selection

I'm using FullCalendar plugin on my project, and I'm looking for a solution to forbid user to select saturdays and sundays in the agenda(it's an holidays schedule).
Does someone has a solution ?
I'm not familiar with JavaScript...

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint and set it to only accept Monday-Friday

Comment: THANKS ! I still don't get how i missed that ... Maybe my english is still not good enough. Anyway, that works perfectly, thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

To hide the weekends use the option:

```
weekends: false,
```

You can check the documentation for options:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/weekends

Comment: I dont want to "hide" the weekends (i managed to do that with hiddenDays:[0,6], already), i just want those 2 days to be impossible to click on. But thanks for the idea !